# Power BI Dudas y Preguntas

Tags: powerbi

Me gustaría saber si en un informe subido en la web de Power BI con sus filtros ya aplicados podría exportar como servicios o datos los obtenidos en el propio proceso de filtrado, es decir, obtener los datos filtrados del informe para utilizarlos en una aplicación externa por ejemplo, pero la duda concreta es si tengo alguna forma de acceder a todos esos datos que son filtrados vía web para usarlos en un app

Comment: Lo que estas tratando de hacer es redundante ua que power BI es una herramienta de analisis, hacer lo que dices es trabajar dos veces para obtener el mismo resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, eso no es posible y además no tiene sentido. Power BI es una herramienta de BI (Business Intelligence) y como tal es el último escalón de los datos empresariales, desde que se producen (introducción de la información), pasando por dónde son útiles (procesos empresariales) hasta que ya no son modificables y en ese modo de solo lectura pasan a un BI donde son "reaprovechados".

Power BI es una herramienta, en cuando a datos programáticos, de solo lectura. Dispone de una potentete [REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/rest/api/power-bi/) que permite manejar el entorno (conjuntos de datos, usuarios, tablas, informes, etc.) e incluso importar datos, pero no obtenerlos.

También existe una API de javascript con la que establecer filtros en los informes y "traerlos" a aplicaciones propias de forma embebida, pero de ninguna manera se maneja el concepto de dato, solo el de informe, dashboard o elemento gráfico (tile).

La única forma de exportar datos de Power BI es con las utilidades clásicas, orientadas al usuario final, de exportar un informe a Excel, Power Point, etc. Aunque hay una utilidad muy interesante que es la "**Analizar en Excel**", que permite una conexión con el origen de datos (Power BI Services) y crear una tabla dinámica con los datos, este último punto sería el que más se acercaría a la necesidad que expone la pregunta, pero evidentemente parece insuficiente.

Comment: Muchas gracias por aclarar la duda me estás siendo de gran ayuda en mi desarollo de BI