# Exportar datos en Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

Alguien podría ayudarme quiero exportar el modelo de datos de power BI a cvs o txt aclaro  no hago referencia a una vista (...) si no a todo el modelo de datos.

Intento copiar la tabla pero el modelo tiene mas de 5.000.000 de registro y no me los copia todos.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Desde dónde quieres hacer la exportación? ¿Desde Desktop? ¿Service?

Answer (score 0):

No puedes pasar un modelo a estos tipos de archivos, pero si puedes hacerlo con los propios datos exportandolos al tipo de archivo que desees.

Answer (score 0):

La única forma de exportar datos de Power BI es con las utilidades clásicas, orientadas al usuario final, de exportar un informe a Excel, Power Point, etc. Aunque hay una utilidad muy interesante que es la "Analizar en Excel", que permite una conexión con el origen de datos (Power BI Services) y crear una tabla dinámica con los datos, este último punto sería el que más se acercaría a la necesidad que expone la pregunta, pero evidentemente parece insuficiente

Citando al usuario Roger Torne

[Power BI Dudas y Preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/308443/power-bi-dudas-y-preguntas?rq=1)